# WindowsFormsHost white first time

Tags: wpf, activex, windowsformshost

I have a WPF window that basically has this occupying its entire space:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.RowSpan="2" Name="wfh" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Cursor="IBeam" ForceCursor="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
    <ax:AxViewerActiveX x:Name="_axViewer" AutoSize="True"  Cursor="Cross" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" UseWaitCursor="True">
    </ax:AxViewerActiveX>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

The first time I do `ShowDialog()` of this window, the window appears blank:
[image]

The second time it appears as it should:

[image]

Please, can someone help to make the rendering of the window correctly the first time?

Constructor of this window class:

```
this.InitializeComponent();
_axViewer.BeginInit();
_axViewer.EndInit();

Focus();
_axViewer.Focus();
```

When calling it is simple as:

```
w3d.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
w3d.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Contact the owner of the ActiveX control for support

Comment: can you show some codebehind?

Comment: @HansPassant: We are the owners of the ActiveX control

Comment: How about if you just do a `Show`? Just wondering if there are some laggy async messages in the queue when the `ShowDialog` gets called. If the control renders properly in `Show` then the problem is with the ActiveX control.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the initialization for the ActiveX control in the .Loaded() method?

```
this.InitializeComponent();
Loaded += delegate {
    _axViewer.BeginInit();
    _axViewer.EndInit();

    Focus();
    _axViewer.Focus();
};
```

Comment: It didn't solve. Anyway, thank you! Seems the problem is on background painting issues of the ActiveX control.